# LINQ 2 SQL Group by multiple custom columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to create LINQ query that will have different grouping fields.
I.E. I have a class

```
 public class Stat
 {
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }
      public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
      public int ActionType { get; set; }
      public string Version { get; set; }
 }
```

Now I need to query table with this data with grouping by several custom fields. For example, group by ApplicationId and ActionType or by Application and Version

I don't want to write different queries for all possible combinations of fields. And want to make a generic method, that will accept list on column names where grouping must occur.

So is there a way to create such a query in runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with **Dynamic Linq:**

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: It's seem to me, that I need to create SQL query directly in string :(

Comment: Or you can create an `If` tree with every possible permutation of queries. Personally, I prefer the Dynamic approach.

Answer (score 0):

By using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library, you can express LINQ queries using extension methods (for example ".Where and .GroupBy") that take **string arguments** instead of type-safe language operators.

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/step2.png))</sub>

Comment: You linked a picture from the article posted by @Robert.